# How to upgrade Firefox OS simulator with nightly Gaia?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-os

I'd like to work with Gaia's Contacts App to verify some of my work.
As far as I can see, simulator 4.0 as well as 5.0pre3 give me just a white page for the Contacts.
I was able to load the nightly Gaia build and see the Contacts app in the standalone b2g.exe.
I also found the descriptions how to build Gaia from source and push it (with a make command from the build) to the OS Simulator, but I would like to avoid the hassle with settimg up a build system withh all tools etc.

Can anybody explain (or point me to) how to upgrade the Gaia in the Firefox Simulator OS?

I'm working on Windows 7, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet here is to [build GAIA for desktop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Using_Gaia_in_Firefox) - if your application doesn't depend on any specific hardware libraries (which are only emulated in the Simulator, and not in the desktop Gaia build) then you'll be just fine.

You might want to link your app in the built GAIA profile via a symlink or similar to ease development and avoid needing to push or update your app on every change.